# Twitter Bootstrap typeahead selection not bound by KnockoutJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, bootstrap-typeahead

Ok, I've fought with this issue for hours now and narrowed the issue to a very simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codepic/3sAmN/)

Problem is, that when I'm using twitter bootstrap's typeahead plugin on a text input and make a selection, the value doesn't update in the KnockoutJS ViewModel. I know I could hack it to work but there must be something that I'm missing here.

Basically what I have is:

**Knockout Binding**

```
// Bind twitter typeahead
ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var typeaheadArr = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        $element.attr("autocomplete", "off")
                .typeahead({
                    'source': typeaheadArr,
                    'minLength': allBindings.minLength,
                    'items': allBindings.items,
                    'updater': allBindings.updater
                });
    }
};
```

**Knockout ViewModel**

```
function MyModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.productName = ko.observable();
    self.availableProducts = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyModel());
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="typeahead:availableProducts, value:productName"/>
```

The rest of the stuff is simply coming from Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I am not the author of the binding. The original binding is here: https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap I wonder if I missed something in the usage???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to modify your `updater` function where you need to grab the observable used in the `value` binding and update it with the function paramter:

```
'updater': function(item) {
    allBindings.value(item);
    return item;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4xAPD/)

If you are not the author of the binding you than you can use the `updater` option to specify the `updater` function

```
data-bind="typeahead:availableProducts, 
           updater: function(item) { productName(item); return item; }"
```

Because the `updater` should returns the selected item the syntax of this is not so nice.

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rNB8P/)

Comment: Ok, that seems to be working fine. Can you explain why this works vs. the previous implementation? I am not the author of the knockout binding. I would like to understand what the original author thought when he put allBindings.updater into the updater and if there is a 'correct' way to use the binding. Something I'm missing in the HTML maybe? The original plugin is here: https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap

Comment: I didn't know that this binding is in a library. I've modifed my answer to work with the original code. Regarding why the author designed the API in this way I have no idea. I was not abble to find any example on github which uses the `updater` option. So I would say that this is a "API design bug" in the library because we are talking about the ko-bootstrap library which should be more idiomatically use KO. So could imagine something like this as the proper implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/wTRhF/

Comment: I think the original implementation works well with functions rather than simple value binding. Basically updater function does what it needs to do with the selected value, here its to assign to a ko observable. nemesv's solution is a short-cut of that.

Comment: Great! Now I got it! I really enjoy actually understanding why things don't work instead of just getting them to work. However, I don't like the idea of functions. Suppose I need to figure out a way to get this binding working more automagically.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to keep my autocomplete suggestions list separate from Knockout entirely. I only want Knockout to know once a user has actually entered a value.

This is closer to user2576666's technique, since it uses [Typeahead's custom events](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events) to force an update in the Knockout model when there is a selection or an autocompletion. However, it doesn't require a typeahead custom binding, and nor does it require the values to be stored in the Knockout ViewModel. This opens up the scope for more customisable completion down the line (such as using [Bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)), which would get needlessly fiddly if we tried to store it in the Knockout model. My ViewModel is definitely not the right place to store the autocompletion options for my use case (and, I would suggest, many others – particularly if you have potentially large list which needs dynamic population). IMO this version is also easier to understand:

```
var availableProducts = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substrRegex;
    matches = [];
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push({ value: str });
      }
    });
    cb(matches);
  };
};


function MyModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.productName = ko.observable();
}

var myModel = new MyModel();

ko.applyBindings(myModel);

var onUpdated = function($e, datum) {
    myModel.productName(datum.value);
};

$(".typeahead")
    .typeahead(
       {hint: true, minLength: 1, highlight: true},
       {displayKey: 'value', source: substringMatcher(availableProducts)})
    .on('typeahead:autocompleted', onUpdated)
    .on('typeahead:selected', onUpdated); // for knockoutJS
```

I have, of course, saved this as [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangefeatures/BHT2N/9):

Answer (score 3):

This updater stuff didn't work for me, here is what did

```
ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var typeaheadArr = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        var updateValues = function (val) {
            allBindings.value(val);
        };

        $element.attr("autocomplete", "off")
                .typeahead({
                    'local': typeaheadArr,
                    'minLength': allBindings.minLength,
                    'items': allBindings.items,
                }).on('typeahead:selected', function (el, item) {
                    updateValues(item.value);
                }).on('typeahead:autocompleted', function (el, item) {
                    updateValues(item.value);
                });
    }
};
```